# Programming NEMA 17 2 Phase, 4 Wire Stepper Motor

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, stepper

I have successfully programmed the Stepper Motor 28BYJ-48 with ULN2003 driver using the code below. But then I replaced the 28BJY-48 with a NEMA 17 Motor then it won't work anymore. I researched that the 28BJY-48 is a 4 phase stepper motor and the NEMA 17 is a 2 phase stepper motor. Is there a difference on how should I programmed a 2 phase stepper motor from a 4 phase stepper motor?

```
#define A        2                     // the pin connected to the wire A of the coil A (or to the H-bridge pin controlling the same wire) 
#define A_bar    3                     // the pin connected to the wire A- of the coil A (or to the H-bridge pin controlling the same wire)
#define B        4                     // the pin connected to the wire B of the coil A (or to the H-bridge pin controlling the same wire)
#define B_bar    5                     // the pin connected to the wire B- of the coil A (or to the H-bridge pin controlling the same wire)
#define x        4000                  // smaller values may make the motor produce more speed and less torque
#define stepsPerRevolution 200         // you can the number of steps required to make a complete revolution in the data sheet of your motor


void setup() {
  pinMode(A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A_bar, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B_bar, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {  
  for (int i = 0; i < (stepsPerRevolution/4) ; i++) {
    digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(A_bar, LOW);
    digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(B_bar, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds (x);

    digitalWrite(A, LOW);
    digitalWrite(A_bar, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(B_bar, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds (x);

    digitalWrite(A, LOW);
    digitalWrite(A_bar, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(B, LOW);
    digitalWrite(B_bar, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds (x);

    digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(A_bar, LOW);
    digitalWrite(B, LOW);
    digitalWrite(B_bar, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds (x);
  }


  /*// Counter Direction 
  for (int i = 0; i < (stepsPerRevolution/4); i++) {
    digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(A_bar, LOW);
    digitalWrite(B, LOW);
    digitalWrite(B_bar, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds (x);

    digitalWrite(A, LOW);
    digitalWrite(A_bar, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(B, LOW);
    digitalWrite(B_bar, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds (x);

    digitalWrite(A, LOW);
    digitalWrite(A_bar, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(B_bar, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds (x);

    digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(A_bar, LOW);
    digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(B_bar, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds (x);
  }
  delay(1000);*/
}
```

I changed the stepsPerRevolution to 200 for NEMA 17 and 32 for the 28BJY-48. NEMA 17 does not work.

Comment: `Is there a difference on how should I programmed a 2 phase stepper motor from a 4 phase stepper motor?` .... it is up to you to research the differences between the two ... once you have the information, the solution may become obvious

Comment: You can’t use a ULN2003 to drive a bi-polar stepper motor.

Comment: I see that others used L293D, so I can use that with the same code?